# Is there a way to get access keys using user pool user and no AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I have a Java backend service and i want to use AWS Cognito to provide authentication and access to AWS services. This service do not have any information about the AWS account. I see that all the clients required AWS credentials or admin credentials for their creation. How can i give access to this service with only using a user from the user pool without any knowledge of the AWS account?

I have tried the client side and server side but they both need aws credentials to create a user pool and identity pool client which then can get access tokens.

```
        try {
            credentials = new ProfileCredentialsProvider("default").getCredentials();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new AmazonClientException(
                    "Cannot load the credentials from the credential profiles file. " +
                    "Please make sure that your credentials file is at the correct " +
                    "location (/Users/ayushaws/.aws/credentials), and is in valid format.",
                    e);
        }

        // Creating Cognito user pool client
        AWSCognitoIdentityProvider client = AWSCognitoIdentityProviderClientBuilder.standard()
                .withRegion("us-east-1")
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials))
                .build();
```

This is how i am currently creating my client. My question is this requires my credentials initially to create a client. How do we create a client if the app using is outside of AWS and have no knowledge of AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be using credentials with sufficient privileges to create the Cognito User Pool and the Cognito Identity Pool. Since you're using Cognito you should be able to handle auth and access in your client side application, and your application does not need long term credentials, as Identity Pool will provide the necessary credentials.

In your client application, the user will login to the Cognito User Pool directly.  When they successfully login to the User Pool they'll receive a response which includes an `IdToken`. You then add the `IdToken` to the credentials map and that will grant the user access to the resources that the Identity Pools Authenticated IAM role permits.

You can read more about how to use Cognito User Pools in conjunction with Cognito Identity Pools in the [AWS Cognito docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html).